# Magento2 | Can't connect to Market place --> Encountered end of file

Tags: marketplace

some how I am unable to connect to marketplace, does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I already tried a composer install, there you also have to authenticate with the public and private key and that seems to work fine. If i try to sing in and try to link my Market place, I get the infamous "Encountered End of File" error again.

Been busy with this for quite a while now... No one knows a solution????

Answer (score 0):

[image]**YES, I found the solution!!!!!**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b5700fe2da786e8615d10a77647397382804c37c

Hope I can help someone else with this. please let me know if this was helpful!